# Link to a section in another page

Tags: html

I'm having an issue with my links, even tho I think it will be extremely straight forward, but I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

In my homepage i have two sections #portfolio and #contact. Then i have a folder with all the portfolio projects displayed.

My homepage sections are strucuted like this:

```
<section class="zonas" id="contact" name="contact">
            CONTENT
        </section>
```

On all my portfolio pages i have the menu as this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../index.html#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="../index.html#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

I want that when clicked on Portfolio, por example, that the user is taken back to the Portfolio section on the homepage. So far, only the "Home" menu item works. Both Portfolio and Contact doesn't. It doesnt do anything. Even tho when i over it i cant see on the left bottom corner the link "mydomain.com/index.html#portfolio

As i saw in other similar threads, i already tried "/index#portfolio" , "/index.html/#portfolio" but the result is the same.

Comment: If your other pages are in the same directory than your homepage, the link should look like: `href:index.html#portfolio`. If they are in a subdirectory, your links are correct. When you say that it doesn work... what do you mean? Do the links reach at least the homepage? If you place a link `index.html#portfolio` inside the homepage... do you reach the correct section?

Comment: That's correct. In order to check in the problem with your links is not the address, replace the non-working links with just your domain, or google.com, or whatever. Do they work? If they don't work at all... are they maybe hide under a transparent `div` or similar? do you have any piece of JavaScript interfering with their normal behavior?

Comment: @David Those pages are inside a folder, so i used ../ to go up one level. The links don't do anything. I click and nothing happens. If i place in the homepage, yes they do work and reach the correct section

Comment: @David i just replaced the links with my domain and they work. No, i dont have any JS interfering

Comment: @David I also replaced the ".." for my domain and the same issue presist

Comment: If I understood you, href="../index.html" works; but href="../index.html#portfolio" doesn't work and you **can't** (maybe a mistype and meant **can**) even see the little tooltip/popup with the URL. In other words, the link breaks if you add the anchor part (hash). Is that correct?

Comment: I run out of ideas so I will insist in the JS one. There is some JS involve, maybe not yours, but from Bootstrap or other libraries. Get rid of all JS (especially any kind of smooth scrolling library) and try again.